# Статистика по генерируемому трафику в yandex-tank

Tags: яндекс-танк

Имеется ли возможность выводить танком статистику по объему исходящего\входящего трафика создаваемого генератором?

Answer (score 1):

В консоли во время выполнения теста пишется средний размер запроса и ответа на текущем рпс и за последнюю секунду.

[image: скриншот консоли]

Comment: Это да, но интересует немного другое: есть ли возможность выводить статистику в бит\сек., Мбит\сек. и т.д. по rx\xt-рингам порта, через который связаны генератор с мишенью?

Comment: Можно настроить мониторинг https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#configuration, правда встроенные метрики позволяют собирать суммарную статистику за определенный интервал по всем интерфейсам

Comment: Мониторинг уже включен, но данная статистика собирается с сервера мишени. К сожалению, данный вариант тоже не подходит...